# Finding surface area - integral of $\sqrt{1+z^2}$

Tags: integration, surfaces

Sorry about this, this is more of a "am I going the right way" question, there's a surface it goes:

$$x^2+y^2-z^2=1$$

Now this is nice because
$x^2+y^2=r^2=1+z^2$ thus $r=\sqrt{1+z^2}$ (I want the positive side)

(BORING PART - I am sure this is right)

So the shape of this thing has rotational symmetry about z (the vertical axis) some sort of hyperbola comes to mind because it has (for r) two parts (the + and -) and it "tends to linear" as z gets large.

That's not analysis reasoning, just for large $z$ $z^2$ will be pretty big compared to one, so $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ will be slightly bigger than $z$.

Anyway, my task is to find the surface area between the planes z=1 and z=0.

So.... the circumfrence of a circle is $2\pi r$and $r$ is as above. The height of each 'lil cylinder is $dz$ (This was once fine, Analysis makes me feel bad for saying this!) so $dA = 2\pi\sqrt{1+z^2}dz$ It makes sense to sum from $z=0$ to 1, hence:

**ACTUAL QUESTION**
$$A = 2\pi\int^1_0\sqrt{1+z^2}dz$$

I am pretty sure I am being dippy by not seeing it, I can see that:

using $\cosh(\theta)^2-\sinh(\theta)^2=1$ one can easily get to:
$\cosh(\sinh^{-1}(z)) = \sqrt{1+z^2}$

The question is supposed to be easy, just wondering if there's a quicker way, someone to go "yes that's right!" would be great.

Comment: In latex, use "\int^{1}_{0}" or "\int^1_0" for that. And precede cos, cosh, sin etc. with a "\", so that $cos$ becomes $\cos$. Better?

Comment: Here's a link on that integral: http://planetmath.org/integrationofsqrtx21

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I tried a slash with arcsinh and it didn't work, but yes better, I assumed taht when the arcsinh failed the others wouldn't work either, thanks for the integral thing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For future people looking for an answer, the integral in the question is totally wrong. I'd gone the wrong direction.

To see an answer that uses the rotational symmetry about the z axis of the question (ie elementary .... tapered disks (NOT cylinders)) please see Ron Gordon's answer.

To have your memory jogged (subtly getting my excuse in there) about surface area, read on.

It ought to be known that a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be parameterised by a map $\boldsymbol{r}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$
and by analogy a surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by:

$\boldsymbol{r}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$

The surface $S =\lbrace\boldsymbol{r}((u,v))|(u,v)\in\Omega\rbrace$
From now on I'll write r(u,v) as r of the vector (u,v), save some brackets.

and: $\Omega=\lbrace(u,v)|u\in U, v\in V\rbrace$

tl-dr parametric surface.

Now neglecting questions of existence (a smooth way of pretending I'm not sidestepping answering those questions) the following all happens:
with the substitution involving root 2, it should be 1 over root 2du not root2du
consider the parallelogram (with curvy edges maybe, but for small enough delta u and v will exist such that the four 'edges' do not cross, which is what is important):

$\boldsymbol{r}(u,v)$

$\boldsymbol{r}(u+\delta u,v)$

$\boldsymbol{r}(u,v+\delta v)$
and

$\boldsymbol{r}(u+\delta u,v+\delta v)$

the area of a parallelogram can be found quite easily by showing that (looking at it so one of the sets of parallel lines is 'an x axis' and reflecting is (isometry) as required so the slanty edge is to the right, ie the top now horizontal line ends to the right of the base) you can 'cut off' a triangle that starts at the right end of the base, defined by going vertically upwards from that, then right to the end of the top edge,

and that it fits with the bottom right vertex being the top vertex of a similarly constructed triangle on the other side.

This sounds so much harder than my simple picture, but just use an angle "theta" from the base to the left slanty edge, if you continue the base, there's another angle theta from that base to the right slanty edge. cos defines the 'overhang' it's very easy to show they're similar triangles.

Thus you can turn the parallelogram into a rectangle, of width |b| (b for the base vector) and height |a|sin(theta) where a is the vector that is the slant, and |a| the length of it

So the area is |a||b|sin(theta)

Now you should know that a x b = |a||b|sin(theta)n where n is a unit normal vector to a, b (perpendicular to them both)

so |a x b| = | |a||b|sin(theta)n | = |a||b|sin(theta) |n| = |a||b|sin(theta)

this means the magnitude of the cross product of the (direction) vectors that represent the edges of the parallelogram is the area of that parallelogram.

So going back to our parallelogram, we can see that:

$\boldsymbol{r}(u+\delta u,v)-\boldsymbol{r}(u,v)\approx\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{u}}\delta u$

and

$\boldsymbol{r}(u,v+\delta v)-\boldsymbol{r}(u,v)\approx\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{v}}\delta v$

Which are the edges of the 'parallelogram'

the area of which is ($\approx$):

$\lVert\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{u}}\delta u\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{v}}\delta v\rVert=\lVert\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{u}}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{v}}\rVert\delta u\delta v$

Thus: $\int\int_S ds=\int\int_\Omega \lVert\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{u}}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial{v}}\rVert dudv$

I really really .... want to stop typing now, so skipping working out all that you get:

$A=\int^{u=1}_{u=0}{\sqrt{1+2u^2}\int^{v=2\pi}_{v=0}{dv}du}$

Clearly the integral involving v is just 2pi, the second one, I just said, let sinh(t)=root(2)u and got a new integral with limits arcsinh(root(2)) and 0, blah blah blah, answer is:

$A=\pi[\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})]$

Comment: I think you got the gist of it.  To get a nicer look, use a double dollar sign on each side; "edit" my solution to see how I laid it out.

Comment: @RonGordon of course, didn't think of the edit button, thanks again, I'll leave you be now.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is incorrect, although your approach is certainly in the right spirit.  The "height" of a cylinder is not $dz$, but $ds$, or the arc length element along the surface.  In this case

$$ds = \sqrt{1+\left ( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right)^2} dz = \sqrt{1+\frac{z^2}{1+z^2}}dz = \sqrt{\frac{1+2 z^2}{1+z^2}}dz$$

Then the integral for the surface area is instead

$$2 \pi \int_0^1 dz \, \sqrt{1+2 z^2}$$

You can then make a substitution $u=z \sqrt{2}$ to get

$$\sqrt{2}\pi \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} du \, \sqrt{1+u^2}$$

Substituting $u=\sinh{v}$ produces a simpler integral to evaluate.  The result I get for the surface area is

$$S =  \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \left [\sqrt{6} + \log{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})}\right]$$

Comment: For over 2 years now (since doing Volumes of revolution at A-level and later shells in mechanics with moments of inertia) I have wondered why this works, I understand that with my one (I feel so silly, thanks so much) dz stays the same, but I was summing over radius x each dz, which is what lulled me into think I was right, yet with volume one may use dz, could you tell me the topic, what I must find, so that I can see this through the goggles of Analysis please @RonGordon I can see why, but it's wooly, I'd like rigorous proof.

Comment: @AlecTeal: rigorous I cannot provide here (google "surface area" and you'll see how hairy it gets in general).  I think of it this way: for volume., the error in neglecting the slope of the edge of an element is negligible next to the volume of the flat interior.  For surface area, there is no flat interior, so the relative error is too great to neglect the slope; thus we include the "inclination factor" from the arc length element.

Comment: that's what I've been doing, but that isn't very formal, why don't the others work, I get that sum of dz is the same regardless and such but this isn't very formal, why do others fail, why do they - converge for want of a better word to different things? could you point me in the right direction a bit more specifically than "google surface area" please. Thanks, brilliant answer btw, much appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_surface#Tangent_plane_and_normal_vector

Comment: Your answer is wrong by the way, you get 2+z^2 in the first integral you write, it should be 1+2z^2. I should have just thought about it some more, the cylinders (or cones with tops chopped off) is not the definition, instead considering the surface leads to it. I'll answer this tomorrow and put the details in there. thanks @RonGordon I don't really know how to tell when an approximation works, but it now occurs to me that they are not the definition! Thanks

Comment: @AlecTeal: very sorry about the sloppy error.  The technique is correct and I fixed the result FWIW.  (Nobody else answered so I may as well correct it.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks again for your help, also it's still wrong... it's only small though, you should have pi(root(3) + ln(root(2)+root(3))/root(2)), not entirely sure what you've done though sorry, I just let sinh(theta)=root(2)u where my u is your z (I parameterized it as a surface), I would edit it for you but I'm not sure of the etiquette here, people edit mine freely though :P

Comment: @AlecTeal: yeah, I likely deserve it at this point.  One mistake avalanches into others.  But I think what I have is it now.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me, I didn't mean "I'll edit for you" as an insult btw, you don't 'deserve it' I was trying to be helpful in return!

Comment: @AlecTeal: no insult taken.  All is good.  I commend you for finding the mistake and working the problem through; not everyone does that.  (And in hindsight, I'm a little glad it worked out that way - it is to your benefit.)  I hope you understand how surface area works - it is far from trivial as you can see.

Comment: It took me a while but I finally finished my answer, it doesn't look as nice as yours (did I use \frac properly? I skimmed/searched ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf ) could you comment on it with what's wrong? I hope typing latex becomes more natural with time, I think scanning my work would have been quicker! @RonGordon